Creating an inline-block element using the createElement function
I need to add an <a> link to the end of a paragraph - using a function.
I tried to add a element.style.display = "inline-block" to it - but that doesn't seem to work.
I guess I must put the <a> inside the <p> itself, but I haven't seen anything about that anywhere, I know there is only:
a getElementById(idName).appendChild(letA) - which adds the element after the specified html element.
and getElementById(idName).insertBefore(letA) - which adds the element before the html element or replaces it with one of its children.
Is there any way in JavaScript to make something like that:
<p>
   blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
   blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
   blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
   <a>
</p>

Here is my code:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <p>
        fsdfdfkdsfsmdfskfsgsv snbk skv sdnsskfjdsfskdfsfs
        <br>
        <br>
        fsdfdfkdsfsmdfskfsgsv snbk skv sdnsskfjdsfskdfsfs
        <br>
        <br>
        fsdfdfkdsfsmdfskfsgsv snbk skv sdnsskfjdsfskdfsfs
        <br>
        <br>
        fsdfdfkdsfsmdfskfsgsv snbk skv sdnsskfjdsfskdfsfs
        <br>
        <br>
        fsdfdfkdsfsmdfskfsgsv snbk skv sdnsskfjdsfskdfsfs
        <br>
        <br>
        fsdfdfkdsfsmdfskfsgsv snbk skv sdnsskfjdsfskdfsfs
        <br>
        <br>
        fsdfdfkdsfsmdfskfsgsv snbk skv sdnsskfjdsfskdfsfs
        <br>
        <br>
        fsdfdfkdsfsmdfskfsgsv snbk skv sdnsskfjdsfskdfsfs
        <br>
        <br>
        fsdfdfkdsfsmdfskfsgsv snbk skv sdnsskfjdsfskdfsfs
    </p>
    
    <script>
        let cube = document.createElement('a');
        cube.style.color = "white";
        cube.style.backgroundColor = "green";

        cube.innerHTML = "hellow whats uppp!!!!"

        document.body.appendChild(cube);

    </script>
</body>
</html>




I forgot to add the code, hold on!!

"that doesn't seem to work" What is the actual issue you're facing with the link?

Where is the href? What are you using a for?

document.body.appendChild appends to the body.  You already mention getElementById(idName).appendChild(letA) so the solution is to find a way to select that <p> so that you can append to it.  Obvious option (given the code you know) is to give the p an id=.   There are other methods to select elements, such as document.querySelector("p") which gets the first p element.

You're understanding is wrong. appendChild does not add the element after the specified html element. It adds it at the end of the list of children of a specified element.

Yeah, I tried it like that: "document.getElementByTagName('p').appendChild(cube);" - but it does not seem to work, what's the problem with it? @fdomn-m

Right!! I forgot! that might have caused the issue @Reyno

Did you look at my answer @user25017272? I've suggested that a few minutes ago.

It wouldn't be document.getElementByTagName('p').appendChild(cube);. It would be: document.getElementsByTagName('p').appendChild(cube); (elements, not element) and you shouldn't use that old method anyway, use document.querySelector("p").

No @fdomn-m and @Scott, there is no getElementByTagName, it's always getElementsByTagName, so you'll get a dom collection and not a single item as you suggest.

@ScottMarcus You forgot the index from "it would be" part.

What does 'querySelector' refer to? I thought it refers only to the class name @ScottMarcus

I just saw your question, thank you very much!! @0stone0

You can pass any valid CSS selector to querySelector, so you can pass a tag type, a class, an id, a relative position, etc.

@0stone0 Yes, I was just pointing out the missing s in the code, but you are right that you can't call .appendChild on a collection.

And you shouldn't be using .innerHTML when the string doesn't contain any HTML as .innerHTML has performance and security implications. Use textContent instead.

You'll need to use appendChild on the DOM element you want it to be a child of, in your case the <p>


const cube = document.createElement('a');
cube.style.color = "white";
cube.style.backgroundColor = "green";
cube.innerHTML = "hellow whats uppp!!!!"
cube.href = 'https://stackoverflow.com';

const paraf = document.querySelector('p')
paraf.appendChild(cube);
<p>
    fsdfdfkdsfsmdfskfsgsv snbk skv sdnsskfjdsfskdfsfs
    <br>
    <br>
    fsdfdfkdsfsmdfskfsgsv snbk skv sdnsskfjdsfskdfsfs
    <br>
    <br>
    fsdfdfkdsfsmdfskfsgsv snbk skv sdnsskfjdsfskdfsfs
    <br>
    <br>
    fsdfdfkdsfsmdfskfsgsv snbk skv sdnsskfjdsfskdfsfs
    <br>
    <br>
    fsdfdfkdsfsmdfskfsgsv snbk skv sdnsskfjdsfskdfsfs
    <br>
    <br>
    fsdfdfkdsfsmdfskfsgsv snbk skv sdnsskfjdsfskdfsfs
    <br>
    <br>
    fsdfdfkdsfsmdfskfsgsv snbk skv sdnsskfjdsfskdfsfs
    <br>
    <br>
    fsdfdfkdsfsmdfskfsgsv snbk skv sdnsskfjdsfskdfsfs
    <br>
    <br>
    fsdfdfkdsfsmdfskfsgsv snbk skv sdnsskfjdsfskdfsfs
</p>




I'd like to point to Element: insertAdjacentHTML and/or Element: insertAdjacentElement here. It makes targeting of a new HTMLElement (either HTML string or real Element) easier.


const container = document.querySelector(`div[data-demo]`);

// Append link using HTML
container.insertAdjacentHTML(
  `beforeend`, 
  `<a class="whiteOnGreen" href="#">Hello! What's up?</a>` );

// Insert new (P) Element before the second paragraph
let newP = document.createElement(`p`);
newP.className = `blue`;
newP.textContent = `Inserted paragraph`;

container.querySelector(`:nth-child(2 of p)`)
  .insertAdjacentElement(`beforebegin`, newP);

// Insert new (H3) Element before the first paragraph
container.insertAdjacentElement(
  `afterbegin`, 
  Object.assign(
    document.createElement(`h3`), 
    {className: `red`, textContent: `Inserted header`} )
);
.whiteOnGreen {
  color: white;
  background-color: green;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}

.blue {
  color: blue;
}
<div data-demo="1">
  <p>Paragraph 1</p>
  <p>Paragraph 2</p>
</div>




Hey, thank you very much for your help! But just a question: What's exactly the difference between 'insertAdjacentHTML' and 'insertAdjacentElement' - and what else are they used for? Thank you!!

@user25017272 one inserts HTML (a string) and the other inserts an Element (an object) - see the code provided:  Object.assign(document.createElement...

At first you must create element.
Then you need to edit it with href or text.
And then use appendChild().
If you want to add it at the beginning use prepend();
let myTargetParagraph = document.getElementById("IdOfMyElement");

let a = document.createElement("a");
a.textContent = "My desired text";
a.href = "https://www.example.com";

myTargetParagraph.appendChild(a);


Doesn't this just re-iterate what OP said in the question?   Seems that way to me

Just read in MDN that 'textContent' is better to use than 'innerHtml' as it's more secure: "but textContent has better performance because its value is not parsed as HTML. Moreover, using textContent can prevent XSS attacks." Thank you for your help!
